# Burninate the [workaround] tag

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Could the [workaround](/questions/tagged/workaround) tag be burninated? At the moment, it seems to be for anything and everything that the questioner wants a workaround for -- for that reason, it seems to me that it's a meta tag, which makes it unsuitable as a tag on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[All gone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workaround)

[image: Killed!]

Comment: It's now tag number *one hundred thirty-two* on my daily kill list.

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever seen on any SE site.  +100000000000.